# my colab notebook crash, how can i resolve it?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

i got this message when i wanted run a beysian personalized ranking by GPU in colab, How can i resolve this problem ?

message is :

GPU training requires factor size to be a multiple of 32 - 1. Increasing factors from 100 to 127.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that google colab is running out of ram
why?
because we are loading all data at once.or generating all data at once.
example :
google colab having 12 GB of ram. and it running out of ram.

So what i would suggest is:
we can process that data in chunks. if the total size of the data is 12 GB. than we can divide it into chunk(file) of 1 Gb.
12 GB data = 12 chunks(files) of 1 Gb
so now we have to load only 1 GB file into ram. which won't crash our notebook.

Answer (score 0):

On Colab a multitude of things could lead to crash. It's likely that you ran out of RAM or out of GPU memory.